# repeat a if else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

How do I make it after the if statement comes true it will not execute and I can re-enter another set of numbers?... to stop it though i will have it to enter -1 to exit.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    {
        // first enter 2016, then 2000, then 2015 and get multiple results
        int Year;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a year: ");
        Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 != 0)) // <--- entered 2016
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Year you have entered is a Leap Year {0}.", Year);
        }
        if ((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 == 0)) // <--- year 2000
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the 2000 works", Year);
        }
        if ((Year % 5 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0)) // <--- year 2015
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2015 works", Year);
        }
        else
        {
            // startover
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a bit? What do you mean you don't want it to execute when the if statement is true? Do you perhaps mean exit? As far as I can tell (assuming the `else` statement really is empty), every input will print something (or nothing) and then exit, so you can run the application again. Do you want it to go back to `Please enter a year` once an output has been given?

Comment: Btw, not really the issue here but I believe the leap year condition should be `(Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

It is bit unclear, since you want to recur the process until you press `-1`, you could do something like this .

int Year;

```
do  
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a year: ");
    if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Year))
    {
          Console.WriteLine("invalid input");
          continue;
    }

    if ((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 != 0)) // <--- entered 2016
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Year you have entered is a Leap Year {0}.", Year);
    }
    if ((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 == 0)) // <--- year 2000
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the 2000 works", Year);
    }
    if ((Year % 5 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0)) // <--- year 2015
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2015 works", Year);
    }


}   while(Year != -1);

//Console.ReadLine(); not required.
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DNOZAx)

Comment: It's to check if it is a leap year. after i enter 2016 and get that result, i need to be able to enter another year without it exiting

Comment: What if it is not leap year? what is expected behavior in this case?

Comment: The year {0} is not divisible by 4, is not divisible by 100, is not divisibly by 400, and is not a leap year. That is what appears if it is not a leap year when i enter 2015

Comment: Yes, that's correct, what do you want to do when use enters non leap year? do you want to ask for input again or exit?

Comment: Check the demo code I have given, you should try and execute it multiple times with different inputs.

Comment: I used it and it worked fine. "Please enter a year (-1 to quit): " just once i enter -1 it does not just automatically exit. must hit another key

Comment: That's true, you need to _remove_ last line `Console.ReadLine();` , I mentioned that point in the answer :-)

Comment: gotcha. all good now, just have to have an "invalid input" before the first if statement. enter letters instead of numbers and it says "Invalid input. Please enter a year (-1 to quit): ". but other than that thanks for the help

Comment: Included that validation as well.

Comment: Please accept this as answer (the green check image) if this is answer to question and working solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just testing to see if the year entered is a leap year, you could just use DateTime.IsLeapYear()

```
if(DateTime.IsLeapYear(Year))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Year you have entered is a Leap Year {0}.", Year);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Year you have entered is NOT a Leap Year {0}.", Year);
}
```